# How to make foreign key optional between two columns in one MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys

I want to make foreign key optional between two columns in one table. **I know foreign key can be NULL** but I already have data and I have to alter the table. **FOREIGN KEY CAN BE NULL** is not working when you already have data in a table.

For example, I have one table having columns ***id***, ***domain_id***, ***subdomain_id*** and ***content***. What I want to do is I either want to put foreign key in ***domain_id*** or ***subdomain_id*** but not in both.

I thought to make pivot table named **sites** with **id**,**domain_id** and **subdomain_id** but again, I have to think about how I will link that using foreign key with **domain_id** and **subdomain_id**.

MySQL allows us to set foreign keys if a table is already populated with data? I am totally confused on what to do. I am using Laravel migrations for this so let me know if there is some function in Laravel too!

Comment: Is this MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? Be careful with tags.

Comment: Sorry for adding sql-server. I did that by mistake.

Comment: No big deal, just clarifying so we can give you the right answer.